# with ./mange.py syncdb getting permission denied in django project

Tags: python, mysql, django, permission-denied, django-syncdb

```
root@domU-xx-xx-39-04-x5-36:/opt/sana# ./manage.py syncdb
-bash: ./manage.py: Permission denied
```

I tried both `django.db.backends.mysql` and `mysql` for 'ENGINE'
I am able to connect to root using

```
mysql -u root -p
```

My settings.py file is correct
My Django version is 1.1.1 on Ubuntu LTS 10.04 in EC2

Comment: for the creation of database tables .

Comment: the ``manage.py`` script can be executed? what gives you ``ls -l manage.py``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `manage.py` has execute permission. If not give it by

```
# chmod +x manage.py
```

Comment: it worked for me.thanks but how do I check manage.py has execute permission before and after doing chmod +x manage.py . I found no change in manage.py file

Comment: the permissions are filesystem stuff, you can check using ``ls -l manage.py`` and looking for an ``x``. For more information look at ``man chmod``.

Answer (score 0):

**List permissions:**

```
ls -l
```

**If it has x permission on the first 3 characters "--x":**

```
./manage.py syncdb
```

**Also, you are able to execute it using python just with read permission "r--":**

```
python manage.py syncdb
```